# Object is hollow with boolean modifier

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier

I was following this [YouTube tutorial @5:27](https://youtu.be/WxMwa0njGSM?t=327) where we can see that the object is full inside. But when I try to reproduce, it's hollow (1st and 2nd are mine, 3rd is tutorial screenshot)

[image: Mine]

[image]

[image: Tutorial]

Searching on google I see that being hollow is normal for Blender, but that doesn't explain how the tutorial author made it solid by default?

Boolean modifier is applied on Anvil (=cube), as Difference with the Cylinder. Also the author has version 2.78.5 while I have 2.82.

[image]

Comment: Your cylinder is in a really odd place. Would you mind positioning it the way Andrew positioned his in the video?

Comment: Hum I think you mistake the circle below anvil for Cylinder. It's actually just a circle I have removed it, please see another picture I added. Anvil is mirrored, so it's from the other angle

Comment: Okay, it's way more clear now. Well your problem is really odd since Boolean should definitely produce new faces after the cutaway. Are you positive that your object had a closed geometry before the Boolean modifier (was manifold)?

Comment: I have zero idea what you are talking about :) It was a default cube which I shaped into anvil

Comment: Would you mind sharing your .blend-files via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping! I have added 2 links, one for .blend and the other for .blend1 . I am not sure if ".blend1" was supposed to be here,maybe just a temp file

Comment: Okey actually it happens everytime I cut the object in half (for mirroring). As soon as I do it, the boolean modifier stops creating new faces

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 6 months late for this but I would just like to share an answer since I was also currently doing Andrew's tutorial for the Anvil and I also encountered this problem. I think the issue here is that after deleting the half of the model, you basically declared to Blender that your particular model is open and empty inside and that is why whenever you apply the Mirror modifier, you end up with a hollow model since the base model was hollow in the first place.

The solution I found for this is after deleting the half of the anvil, select all the vertices that were left and press F to create a new face.

[image]
[image]

Then do the rest with the Boolean modifier and the model should be solid inside. And also make sure that the Boolean modifier is on top of the Mirror modifier to see the cut on both sides. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Blender models are always hollow, like a shell. This impression of fullness is due to the way Boolean modifier works